# Una ventana emergente en Javascript puede devolver valores al cerrar?

Tags: javascript, html, botón, parametros, ventana

estoy buscando de programar algo similar al boton de pago de paypal con solo Javacript, en donde al hacer clic se abra una mini ventana emergente con cierta medida (width y height), en dicha ventana le solicita algunos datos al usuario y los envia a algun API externo mediante https, luego de recibir response del API me gustaria cerrar la mini ventana automaticamente y devolverle algun objeto o json a la ventana principal (donde se encuentra el boton) para que sepa que hacer a continuación.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto o una guía donde pueda ver como hacer un botón de pago similar al de paypal?

Tambien quisiera saber si existe una guía de hacer este codigo en una especie de embed para insertar el botón en otras páginas.

Saludos!

Comment: Nix, llevas cuatro años en el sitio, ya sabes que las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son bienvenidas. También recuerda que esperamos nos muestres el código que has intentado, y nos digas **lo que has investigado**. A como está la pregunta, parece que pides hagamos la investigación por ti.

Comment: No suelo usar hacer preguntas aquí realmente, por lo que no se que se considera "bienvenido" o no, tampoco quiero que alguien haga una investigación por mi, simplemente pensaba que si a alguien ya le ha tocado trabajar en algo por el estilo pueda recomendarme alguna guía o una fracción de codigo para comenzar, sino que pase de mi pregunta, por eso mismo no puedo aportar codigo o imagen por que no he empezado, de hecho, no se como empezar tal proeza, siento un poco de comentario en tu critica.
Saludos!

Comment: Quizá sea una buena oportunidad para visitar el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), y leas acerca de [Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), sobre [cuáles temas puedes preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) y [cuáles preguntas debes evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Cuando puedas, por favor presiona el botón editar para añadir la información relevante a tu pregunta. Saludos!